# Redirecting to Another Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

At the risk of sounding dumb.

I am trying to redirect to an action in another controller

here is my code

```
     return this.RedirectToAction("s", "profile", new { id = CleanerId });
```

why is it not working?

"s" is the controller, "profile" is the action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch the `s` and `profile`, you have them reversed. [RedirectToAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToAction%28System.String,System.String,System.Object%29)

Comment: Can't believe it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

That is Very Simple to redirect one controller to another. if you are using are  using Area concept then you can write this code like this:  **return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account", new { area = "Admin" })** and if you not use Area Concept then you can write this kind : **return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account", new { area = "" })** I hope so this article useful to you.